# Laravel sum query using join and distinct

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 2 tables to query using `join`, namely `loans` and `amortizations` table.

`Loans` table has many amortizations, so `loans.id` is a reference to `amortizations.loan_id` in `amortizations` table.

`Loan id:3` exist twice in `amortizations table`, each with a `value=10,800`.
`Loan id:5` also exist twice in `amortizations table`, each with a `value=11,100` and the same goes with `Loan id:11` that also exist twice in `amortizations table` each with a `value=5400`.
When you add this up, the `total` is `54,600`. But I wanted the ids to be distinct so that the values won't add twice. So the total would be equal to `27,300`. My existing query below returns a `54,600` value instead of `27,300` even using `distinct()` in Laravel. How would I achieve this?

`Controller query`

```php
$oneToThirtyDue = Amortization::distinct('amortizations.loan_id')
                ->join('loans', 'loans.id', '=', 'amortizations.loan_id')
                ->select('loans.loan_type',\DB::raw('SUM(loans.loan_balance) as total_val'))
                ->where('amortizations.payment_status',0)
                ->where('amortizations.schedule', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
                ->where('amortizations.past_due', '<=', 30)
                ->groupBy('loans.loan_type')
                ->orderBy('loans.loan_type')
                ->get();
```

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can u switch your join to this and tell us what the result is?

       `Amortization::distinct('amortizations.loan_id')
                ->join('loans', 'amortizations.loan_id', '=', 'loans.id') `

Comment: the result is the same sir

Comment: Try Using all the columns for distinct functions.
`Amortization::distinct('amortizations.load_id','value', 'column3'....)`

Comment: neither it works :(

Comment: The last thing i can come up with is to use the DB::Raw() function to select distinct Amortization.loadId.
You can read about it in detail in the following link:
[link](https://laraveldaily.com/select-with-dbraw-make-your-database-work/).

using DB::raw() should let you use raw sql statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $idsDue = Amortization::distinct()
                           ->select('loan_id')
                           ->where('payment_status',0)
                           ->where('schedule', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
                           ->where('past_due', '<=', 30)
                           ->get();

    $oneToThirtyDue = Loan::select('loan_type',\DB::raw('SUM(loan_balance) as total_val'))
                                  ->whereIn('id',$idsDue)
                                  ->groupBy('loan_type')
                                  ->orderBy('loan_type')
                                  ->get();
```

Comment: Congratulation, you should mark it as correct tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this problem is that the max will be calculated for all rows in the group by before the distinct happens. Meanwhile distinct will run on the whole row, after the max so i does not help.

Therefor i believe a sub query can solve most of your troubles. The approach is to cut down the duplicate in the `Amortization` before joining. This will make the join be a 1 to 1, instead of it sometimes being 2-1 when you have duplicates. Reversing the join for ease and using a group by for avoiding duplicates and getting extra columns with max as they are not in the group by. Got a similar query working on local testing on some test tables, so this should be possible to achieve.

```
$subQuery = Amortization::select(
    'loan_id',
    DB::raw('max(amortizations.id) as id'),
    DB::raw('max(amortizations.payment_status) as payment_status'),
    DB::raw('max(amortizations.schedule) as schedule'),
    DB::raw('max(amortizations.past_due) as past_due')
)->groupBy('loan_id');

Loan::join(DB::raw("($subQuery->toSql()) as amortizations"), 'amortizations.loan_id', '=', 'loans.id')
    ->select('loans.loan_type',\DB::raw('SUM(loans.loan_balance) as total_val'))
    ->where('amortizations.payment_status',0)
    ->where('amortizations.schedule', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('amortizations.past_due', '<=', 30)
    ->orderBy('loans.loan_type');
```

This has to be done with a `DB::raw`, but i can not see any better approach as of now, sub queries outside of select statements is a grey area in `Laravel`.